# Negative form of "it is all about" + NOUN

Tags: negation

Consider the following sentence:

> It is all about being lucky.

meaning that being lucky is the main point, reason or factor.

**How would you put it in a negative form?**

1. *It is NOT all about being lucky*.
2. *It is all NOT about being lucky*.
3. Both can be correct, depending on the context or meaning.

I mean to say that *there are other factors to be considered apart from being lucky*, or that *being lucky is not the main point*.

Comment: I would simply say: 'its all about being unlucky.'

Comment: @JoeKerr It is not the same meaning.

Comment: The second one is certainly incorrect. That leaves the first one, which sounds good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say "it is **not all about** being lucky".

This means there are other factors to be considered apart from luck.

If luck wasn't a factor at all, we could say "none of it is about being lucky" or "it is **not at all about** being lucky". "It is **not about** being lucky" would tend to mean the same, although it leaves open the possibility of luck playing a role.